# Disk in $\mathbb{C}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

This seems to be a really frequently used fact.

> An open disk in $\mathbb{C}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Does anyone know a nice way to construct the homeomorphism? I for some reason can't construct this, yet this is apparently fairly straightforward. I'm looking for a general construction method for these kinds of functions.

Comment: $z \to \frac z {1-|z|}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, what is the intuition for this? Is it a part of a general way of constructing such homeomorphisms?

Comment: It is a standard construction which works in any Euclidean space, and even in normed linear spaces!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your reply, is there somewhere that I can learn more about this particular construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can homeomorph $[0,1)$ to $[0,\infty)$ then you can rotate its graph to get a homeomorphism from the open unit disk with the 2D plane. That is, given $f:[0,1)\to[0,\infty)$ unbounded and strictly increasing (and $f(0)=0$), we can define a map $\overline{f}:D\to\mathbb{C}$ by $f(re^{i\theta})=f(r)e^{i\theta}$.

A nice example might be $f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$.

Kavi's example from the comments is $f(x)=x/(1-x)$.

An example I think is more geometrically interesting though is $f(x)=x/\sqrt{1-x^2}$. If we take a point $(x,y)$ on the unit circle in quadrant $I$ with $y\in[0,1)$ and say the line through $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$ has slope $m$ then the function $f$ is defined by $f(y)=m$. This is a kind of stereographic projection.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a good theorem or lemma that can be used to deduce that a continuous, bijective function is a homeomorphism? (I think this holds for a compact domain and a Hausdorff co-domain, but perhaps there is another theorem I am unaware of) In this case, the domain $[0,1)$ or $D$ is not compact, so I can't apply that theorem.